# How to return the total pageview using Google Analytics SDK?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I am able to return the pageviews for a page. But the API returns those pageviews separated by source. So for page /this-page-slug/ it returns X amount of views for direct, Y for referral, Z for mobile, W for none and so on. I want to get the total pageviews for all sources per path. How can I do that?

This is the function that I am using to get the results:

```
function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:source, ga:medium, ga:pagePath',
    'sort' => '-ga:pageviews');

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2017-08-23',
       '2017-10-04',
       'ga:uniquePageviews,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerSession',
        $optParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find my own solution from Eike's post. The solution was to exclude ga:source and ga:medium from dimensions. Like so:

```
function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
    'sort' => '-ga:pageviews');

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2017-08-23',
       '2017-10-04',
       'ga:uniquePageviews,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerSession',
        $optParams);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way Google Analytics works is that metrics add up and dimensions break metrics down.

If you want to have the total you either add up the metrics per dimension in your query result, or you do a second query without dimensions (that's why the arguments array is called opt(ional)Params in the documentation, because the query works without dimensions, filters etc).

Comment: Hi Eike, thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. You steered me in the right direction. No doubt of that. However, taking dimensions out of the equation was not the solution. I still had to keep the dimensions in. This time, without the ga:source and ga:medium. I will post my solution and give you a vote up. So you know, excluding dimensions returned no useful data.

Comment: I assume I took you too literally when you said "total pageviews for all sources". You probably wanted total pageviews per path for all sources, in which case you'd still need the page path dimension.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific on my question. After you mentioned "per path", I edited my question to be more specific.