# Google Analytics Reporting Method, Retrieve Single Value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-analytics, console-application, google-analytics-api

After spending many hours searching around online for a method that will only retrieve **one** data result, I am beginning to lose hope that you even can. Currently, I am pulling data for the whole month, adding them all together and dividing by the number of days in the month to retrieve the average value. Or, just add them all together.

Let's say that I want just one value from google analytics like:

[image: PageViews]

I just want that value. How would this be done?

Below is my code to retrieve a each day and their page views:

```
double totalPageViews = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string[] scopes = { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };
                var googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
                credentials = googleCredential.CreateScoped(scopes);
                var reportingService = new AnalyticsReportingService(
                    new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credentials
                    });
                var dateRange = new DateRange
                {
                    StartDate = _startDate,
                    EndDate = _endDate
                };
                var sessions = new Metric
                {
                    Expression = "ga:pageviews",
                    Alias = "Sessions"
                };
                var date = new Dimension { Name = "ga:date" };
                var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
                {
                    DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
                    Dimensions = new List<Dimension> { date },
                    Metrics = new List<Metric> { sessions },
                    ViewId = viewid
                };
                var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest
                {
                    ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest }
                };
                var batchRequest = reportingService.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);
                var response = batchRequest.Execute();
                foreach (var x in response.Reports.First().Data.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", string.Join(", ", x.Dimensions), string.Join(", ", x.Metrics.First().Values));
                    totalPageViews = totalPageViews + Convert.ToInt64(string.Join(", ", x.Metrics.First().Values));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Total Views from: 2017-08-01 to 2017-08-31: " + totalPageViews);
                _totalPageViews = Convert.ToUInt64(totalPageViews);
            }
```

The method above returns:

```
20170901: 193
20170902: 40
20170903: 48
20170904: 188
20170905: 269
20170906: 236
20170907: 244
20170908: 233
20170909: 37
20170910: 43
20170911: 207
20170912: 205
20170913: 179
20170914: 222
20170915: 130
20170916: 25
20170917: 66
20170918: 229
20170919: 209
20170920: 224
20170921: 205
20170922: 164
20170923: 29
20170924: 33
20170925: 92
20170926: 210
20170927: 208
20170928: 167
20170929: 166
20170930: 56
Total Views from: 2017-08-01 to 2017-08-31: 4557
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: I am aware that the numbers are the same. I am aware that it is the correct end value that is being pulled, although for other entities like `Avg Session Duration`. Again, i know this can be resolved and coded to return the correct result by manipulating all the data returned, i just want to know if there is a simpler way to retrieve one entity between to dates.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Different language, but this is basically a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573995/how-to-return-the-total-pageview-using-google-analytics-sdk/46579774#46579774

Answer (score 0):

Personally i always used the python SDK to query data but i assume its basically the same. When querying data you can just ask for 1 metric with a range and that will do.

After credentials and all that stuff ...

```
service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:pageviews').execute()
```

Comment: It is more or less the same, although, you have certain methods that i am not able to access.. I really do appreciate the efforts though and thanks for the response <3

Comment: @fluffy Trying reading more of the docs and if your are not restricted to C# tell me and i ll send you the code in python.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help :) i will do some reading, i am currently partially restricted towards c# for now.